# Is it possible to highlight groups of rows in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if there is a way to highlight rows in Pandas dataframe based on values in some specific column? For example:

[image]

As can be seen above, in Col_4, values are different. Therefore, is it possible to highlight rows belonging to distinct values? Or, to make it more complex, highlight rows based on different values in multiple columns?

Comment: you can select rows with complex or easy selections ... but a dataframe is just a memory structure there is no "highlighting" if your asking how to output a csv with preformatted cells, that is not a feature of csvs ... other than that im not sure what you are asking

Comment: Have a look to openpyxl.styles. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["A", "F", "A", "F", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "col2": ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "G", "G", "B"],
        "col3": ["C", "H", "C", "H", "C", "I", "C", "I"],
        "col4": ["D", "E", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E"],
    }
)
```

[image]

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Sort value and add an unique identifier to identical rows
df = df.sort_values(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]).reset_index(drop=True)
df["hash"] = df.apply(lambda x: hash("".join(x)), axis=1)

# Attribut a unique unique color to each identifier
import random

colors = [
    f"#{random.randint(0,255):02X}{random.randint(0,255):02X}{random.randint(0,255):02X}"
    for _ in range(df.shape[0])
]

color_mapping = {}
for value in df["hash"].unique():
    color = colors.pop(0)
    if value not in color_mapping:
        color_mapping[value] = color
```

```py
# Color rows (run in a Jupyter notebook)
df.style.apply(
    lambda v: [f"background-color: {color_mapping.get(v['hash'], '')}"] * df.shape[1],
    axis=1,
).hide_columns("hash")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. There is a small issue. It seem that if the number of unique hashes is greater than the number of the provided colors, the dataframes stops being colored.

Comment: Right. I've updated my answer to deal with this issue. Cheers.